# I want to do the multiple lines in the single plot using the ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am working on a large data set with many rows and columns. The data here is showing is portion of it. I want to put all the values of column b to e against the variable a

I tried the melt function and looks like it doesn't work. Please help me to solve this one by using ggplot2 and if necessary for loop or appy function

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6OG3.png)

Comment: The data is in the "enter the image description here"

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please don't include your data as an image, since it's difficult for people to help you solve your problem if you don't include code they can run on their own machine to reproduce your situation. Take a look at this advice: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `gather()` (library **tidyr**), that will regroup the column *b* to *e* together. Then, you can plot with `ggplot()` and split your graph with the function `facet_grid()`.

```
df %>% 
gather(2:5, key = myColumns, value = myValues) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x = a, y = myValues, color = myColumns)) + 
geom_line() + 
facet_grid(myColumns ~ .)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can you show it putting the all the lines in the same plot instead of four different graph and also avoiding the pipe operator

Comment: To prevent the pipe operator, you can create temporary object. `df2 <- gather(df, 2:5, key = myColumns, value = myValues)`. Then, don't use `facet_grid()` if you want lines in the same graph. The parameter `color =` will create the four lines (one by levels of the variable you give to the parameter).